# Limiting edits to 10 characters is a bad idea

Tags: discussion, edits

Often I'll take a code snippet from Stackoverflow and I try and execute it I find typos which prevent it from executing. After fixing the problems, I'd like to update the answer or question in stack, but sometimes I don't need to edit a few characters--sometimes even only a single character--but rules force me to make 10 character edits. What am I suppose to do? add a 10+ superfluous edit to the code? How is this a good idea? What is the basis for the policy that 'minor edits are a bad thing'? It's a basic fact that many little changes can result in a big overall effect. So I discourage this 'anti-minor edit' policy.

Example, original poster has the wrong variable, it should be 'dateFromFilter' not 'dateFilter'. This is the kind of thing that someone could easily miss and lose hours over.
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18129432/revisions

Comment: *"What am I suppose to do?"* Fix other problems with the answer: grammar errors, formatting errors, spelling errors, etc. Perhaps improve the clarity. Any number of things. Rare is the post that is made *perfect* with an edit < 10 characters.

Comment: Also see: [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77233) and [others](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/76891)

Comment: it's not about minor spelling, formatting and grammar errors at all. It's about CODE errors. The whole purpose of this site is to find solutions to IT problems. So it's a disservice to the community that I cannot make an edit that would transform a broken pieces of code into a working solution.

Comment: @CodyGray `>Rare is the post that is made perfect with an edit < 10 characters`
It's not rare at all that a few characters can radically improve a piece of code. i.e. == vs ===

Comment: posted example to question above

Comment: This doesn't seem to me to be a duplicate of the linked question. That question is asking specifically about formatting changes; this one is asking about making a small edit that changes an incorrect answer to a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about that. When you gain more reputation, this limitation will no longer apply to your edits.
Literally [2000 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) is a threshold. Having this, you can change one character and submit.
But please pay attention when you edit the post. There are almost always more things to improve in the post.

The more SO trusts you, the more privileges you get.

Another thing is that fixing a one letter typo is not a big improvement since most of developers (like you) can fix it on their own.

You have to understand that every edit made by user with low reputation has to be reviewed by other peers. We have a lot of vandalism and invalid edits. Allowing all users to change one character in the question/answer would make a review queue significantly longer.

Comment: I think a few characters which transform someone's off-the-cuff code from a failing solution into a working solution is a great service. Here is an example. The missed having 'from' on the data filter. This is the kind of thing that someone could easily miss and get stuck on for hours. 
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18129432/revisions